# Dynamic Spring Kafka Listener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-el

I am using spring kafka with SPEL and trying to listen to different topics based on the value present in one of the property file.

@KafkaListener(topics="#{kafkaTopics.getTopics().get('${key.in.property}')}")

Now here getTopics is returning a Map of .

All is working fine when I have some String[] being returned from get().

But, in case if get() is returning "" ,i.e. I do not want to subscribe to any topic, then there is some issue.

I am getting IllegalTopicException. **Invalid Topic ''**.

Is there any way to solve this, if I do not want to listen to any topic at runtime?

Comment: you could get the value of "key.in.property" first, and make an if-else statement based on that (subscribe only if value is different than '' " )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` has this option:

```
/**
 * Set to true or false, to override the default setting in the container factory. May
 * be a property placeholder or SpEL expression that evaluates to a {@link Boolean} or
 * a {@link String}, in which case the {@link Boolean#parseBoolean(String)} is used to
 * obtain the value.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return true to auto start, false to not auto start.
 * @since 2.2
 */
String autoStartup() default "";
```

So, you can use your `kafkaTopics.getTopics().get()`as a conditional to determine if you need to start that container or not. Only if container is started, it is subscribing to the topics it is configured for.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working as I was expecting.